# Nodejs connect to database or REST service

Tags: mysql, database, json, rest, node.js

I have to choice to output the info in database (Mysql) to be json format.

1. directly connect to database and fetch the data and output json
2. connect to a REST service to get the data and output json.

Which is better and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> directly connect to database and fetch the data and output json

If you are connecting to the database (doesn't matter if it's MySQL or something else) directly through binary based protocol it should be faster than REST based protocol.

> connect to a REST service to get the data and output json.

REST based protocols are on the other hand more simple, straightforward and easier to implement from the client side of view than binary ones in general.

> Which is better and why?

It depends if you need speed or simplicity of use. In case of binary connection you would additionaly have to parse fetched data to JSON. REST service can give you usually just what you need in desired JSON format. However if speed is crucial for you then binary protocol is better choice I would say.

Comment: I know that nodejs is good at IO oprations and do not good at CPU intensive operations, is this matters?

Comment: @bruce dou: Fetching data from DB, either through binary or REST protocol, shouldn't be a CPU intensive operation which would "slow down" your program since you are probably not doing any hard computation, but rather waiting for data to be retrieved from DB.